# add rel to drupal_goto function

Tags: drupal-7, lightbox2

I use light box to popup one register node. When we use light box, we need to add rel attribute after the link:

```
<a href="/gopackup/register?format=simple" rel="lightframe[|width:960px; height:390px; scrolling: no;]">Register</a>
```

It works well, but now i need to use drupal_goto function to that page, how can i add the rel? Here is my code:

```
drupal_goto("gopackup/register",array(
'query' => array(
    'format' => 'simple',

),
));
```

The purpose of that code is redirect user to register page.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to add "rel" in the "drupal_goto" function has no sense. There is no such option value available anyway. This is a client side vs a server side story.

In the "a" tag the "rel" attribute value is parsed by the lightbox js to bind a click event and set options to the lightbox.

As far as I understand, what you want to achieve is to trigger the lightbox after the redirection is done.

The only way (unless there is a specific way in the lightbox plugin) to do that is to trigger the click in a custom js once redirection is done (check "trigger" method in jquery). To let the page know that it needs to trigger the lightbox you can use a hash/fragment in the URL (#showpopup for instance). If you detect the fragment in your custom js, you trigger the event.

You only use the "drupal_goto" function options here to add the fragment in the redirection URL.